# how to play videos in windows mobile by windows media player in full screen mode

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-media-player

hii,

I am developing an application which plays video from the server. I want to know how to play videos in windows mobile  by  windows media player in full screen mode.
The situation is serious because windows media player also shows the url playing which contains the infromation about the internal security of server, so it is highly undesirable.
so can anybody help me in these issues-------------

1// start media player in full screen
2// media player does not stores the previous url.

the code which i m using for this is given below----------------

```
using System.Diagonostics;
 Process objProcess;
 ProcessStartInfo mediaStartInfo;

 objProcess = new Process();
            mediaStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(@"windows\wmplayer.exe", path);
            objProcess.StartInfo = mediaStartInfo;
            try
            {
                objProcess.Start();
            }
            catch (Exception e) { }
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried using the /fullscreen argument like you would on the regular OS and that didn't work.

I'm not sure either is possible by just starting a new version of the media player.  The best way to accomplish both is probably hosting the ActiveX control in your program, then you'll have full control.

Comment: Yes I am using activeX windows media player but the problem is many of teh file formats are either not supported or not played. It even sometimes does not plays mp3 and wma. So I am forced back to use the system media player

Comment: Then there's something wrong with your code.  The built-in WMP uses the ActiveX control itself, so if it works in the player app, then it must work in the control.

Comment: hey suddenly the above code has also stiped working  for the urls